# Understanding interpn function of scipy.interpolate

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I am trying to understand the working of the function `scipy.interpolate`. I created a small setup but it is giving errors. Here is what I did:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.arange(10)
gx, gy = np.meshgrid(x,y)
v = np.ones((10,10))


sample_at = np.random.random((10,10))

interpolated = scipy.interpolate.interpn((gx, gy), v, sample_at)


print(interpolated.shape)
```

This gives an error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    interpolated = scipy.interpolate.interpn((gx, gy), v, sample_at)
File "/home/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py", line 2624, in interpn
    "1-dimensional" % i)
ValueError: The points in dimension 0 must be 1-dimensional
```

What is happening here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are making a wrong assumption wrt the structure of the grid requested by `interpn`

> `ValueError: The points in dimension 0 must be 1-dimensional`

This message, a little bit obscure, references the elements of the grid and tells you that they must be 1-dimensional, or in other words you must call `interpn` not with `(gx, gy)` as first argument but with `(x, y)`.

```
scipy.interpolate.interpn((x, y), v, sample_at)
```

But there is another wrong assumption in your code, because if you use the call above, with your definition of `sample_at`, you'll get a different error

> `ValueError: The requested sample points xi have dimension 10, but this RegularGridInterpolator has dimension 2`

that hopefully has a clearer meaning: if your grid has two dimensions (*x* and *y*, that is) all your points on which `interpn` has to interpolate must be 2-dimensional as well... In other words, in your example the *LAST* dimension of the grid must be `2`

Putting it all together (I'll use a location matrix `sample_at` of 5 rows by 3  columns of 2-D points in this example) we have

```
In [69]: import numpy as np 
    ...: import scipy.interpolate 
    ...: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
    ...:  
    ...: x = np.arange(10) 
    ...: y = np.arange(10) 
    ...: v = np.ones((10,10)) 
    ...: sample_at = 8*np.random.random((30)).reshape(5, 3, 2) 
    ...:  
    ...: scipy.interpolate.interpn((x, y), v, sample_at)                                                       
Out[69]: 
array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])
```

PS: read the source code<sup>1</sup>, the comments in it are much better than the error messages...

---

(1) for me the source code is located at

```
~/lib/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py
```

Comment: This seems to be the opposite of [map_coordinates](scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates) where the output is the first dimension removed for the output shape.